# Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree in foreach

Tags: dart, flutter, android-snackbar

I have a map with loop of markers, for each marker i try to show snackbar with location name. I have a code similar to.

```
     static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey =
              GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
     for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            markers.add(new Marker(
                width: 80.0,
                height: 80.0,
                point: list[1].values.elementAt(i),
                builder: (ctx) => new Container(
                    child: new GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                            duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
                            content: new Text(coords.keys.elementAt(i)),
                            action: SnackBarAction(
                              label: 'Ver',
                              onPressed: () {
                                // Some code to undo the change!
                              },
                            ),
                          ));
                        },
                        child: new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.red[300])))));
          }
        return new Scaffold(
           key: scaffoldKey,
```

When i load this page doesn't load anything and console return

> Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

I figure the error is on the scaffold, for each iteration it's trying to set the same name of globalkey. So i need to identify this key with different name when its does the foreach. Any idea how can i do this?

Comment: Do you use `scaffoldKey` anywhere else in the code ?

Comment: check this link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16630

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `static` modifier from your `final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>` declaration .

```
 final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey =
          GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```